# UICollectionView gets the wrong index

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

My collectionview gets one different index each time its tapped. Thats the code i have implemented:

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

```
if (segue.identifier == "projectsSegue") {
    let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForCell(sender as! MyCell)
    let indexPathItem = indexPath?.item


    let controller = (segue.destinationViewController ) as! ProjectsByCodeViewController


    controller.indexSelected = indexPathItem!


}
```

I do think that all should works correctly, but it does not. What do I need to do? My array has 4 items, and if im on the last one, it detects as the 3rd, and if im on the 1st it detects as the 1st, not the 0 index. And if I start from the end it says index 1. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your textfield 3 frame shouldn't use the cell frame y for its position as content will overlap and mess your layout up for the other items. Every item's frame in a cell is in respect of the cell itself, so you can just make the textfield start 20px down from the top of the cell:

```
var titleField3 = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(15, 20, cell.frame.width - 30, 70))
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your help but it still doing the same. If the array has 4 items, once I get the 3rd one it starts overlapping content (the 4th element displayed on the collection view is overlapped) What else can I do? Add a tag? But how?

Comment: Maybe projectImage should be a fixed height rather than the calculation. Also try cell.clipsToBounds = true in your cellForRowAtIndex

Comment: Thanks for reply but it still doing the same :(

Comment: I have tried also creating a new class and still the same. No one knows what to do?